# How to Send Mail at 10 AM every using hangfire scheduler library ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

How to Send Mail at 10 AM automatically every day using hangfire scheduler library and I Installed hangfire dll also.

Below is my C# code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BackgroundJob.Schedule(
          () => sendmail1(),
          new DateTime(2017, 03, 27, 10, 00, 00));
        }
    }
}

public void sendmail1()
{
   //mailer content
}
```

Please help to out this Issue to send 10 am every day and If any other way also helpful.

Comment: The recurring schedule is prominently displayed right on the homepage of hangfire. http://hangfire.io/

Comment: I did not get you, new in scheduling please can you update answer. @AlexPaven

Comment: Goto the hangfire home page, scroll down to Recurring Jobs, copy code.

Comment: But how to send mail at 10 am, I got this code: RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
    () => Console.WriteLine("Recurring!"),
    Cron.Daily); . @MadMyche

Comment: I got this code help of both alex and myche:  RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate( () => sendmail1(), Cron.Daily); but how to send at 10 am. @AlexPaven

Comment: Hangfire understands the common format of CRON expressions so experiment with the Cron class and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression.

Comment: I am becoming mad to read of widipedia thing but I got Another one not understanding: https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/270 plese can you check this. @AlexPaven

Comment: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html

Comment: Please update answer I dont want links getting confused.  @Chetan  Ranpariya

Comment: Please update answer I dont want links getting confused.  @Chetan  Ranpariya

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is to send email everyday 10 AM that means it's recurring task you want to schedule. For this case `BackgroundJob` class is not the one you should use. You need to use `RecurringJob` class.

If you visit http://hangfire.io/ this can be located easily.

Further exploration to Handfire library classes would have explained about what methods are available for `RecurringJob` class.

`RecurringJob` class has method `AddOrUpdate` and one of its overloads takes four arguments out of which last two are optional.

```
public static void AddOrUpdate(Expression<Func<Task>> methodCall, string cronExpression, TimeZoneInfo timeZone = null, string queue = "default");
```

If you notice, cronExpression is nothing but a `string`. So basically you need to figure out the string which represents the cron expression for daily 10AM schedule.

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html

This link has some ready to use examples of cron expressions and one of them is `0 0 12 * * ?` which means Daily 12 (noon).

You change this to `0 0 10 * * ?` what you get is cron expression for daily 10AM schedule.

And finally your code should look as following.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => sendmail1(), "0 0 10 * * ?");
    }
}
```

This should resolve you issue.

Little bit of extra reading and exploration would have saved 10 hours of your time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Crontab expresions? https://crontab.guru

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("my-email-job", () => SendEmail(), "0 10 * * *");
```